# How to find the upper limit of hardware decoder instances for Google Pixel 2 phone

Tags: android-mediacodec, decoder, x264

Can anyone please tell me how to check how many hardware decoder instances (OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc)can be created in my android phone (i.e. Google Pixel 2) for decoding H.264 video stream?

How to check this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file on your phone: `/etc/media_codecs.xml` wich lists all available codecs and it's 'Quirks', 'Limits' and 'Features'. As of android 6 i think there is a 'Limit' called `concurrent-instances`. Every Codec should have that value.

E.g. `<Limit name="concurrent-instances" max="16" />`

This still doesn't guarantee that you can have 16 instances of a specific codec running at the same time as it is also dependent on other factors like bitrate, resolution in conjunction with HW resources. See it as more of an upper most limit of Codecs.

I've seen devices where you could only have a single FHD instance decoder operating at the same time while the `concurrent-instances` was set to `16`. So it is still highly device depended.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I didn't find any media-codec.xml under /etc/ inside Google Pixel 2. The android version I am using is 8.1.0. can u plz tell me whether there is any other files possible?

Comment: I don't have a pixel 2, sorry, but i've checked with a pixel 3 and a Nexus 5 and both have the file `/etc/media_codecs.xml`. I find the file in Android Studios integrated file explorer and using the Total Commander App. Do you see XML files in the /etc/ folder? There schould be more of them.

Comment: I can see .xml files (e.g. apns-conf.xml, old-apns-conf.xml)  but not that one.